# how to convert an NSarray of NSdictionaries to a XML file?

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, nsarray, nsdictionary

How to convert an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` to a XML file?

here is the example! i want to conver this `NSArray`  of `NSDictionaries` to a XML file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have any specific requirements for the XML scheme, then you can just write the NSArray out as a plist file.

More here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1

Comment: Plist file is xml file only. so its one and the same thing that whether you give xml extension which will be for other system and plist for specifically iphone